# How to get pagenumbers in listoffigures ragged-right?

Tags: table-of-contents

Maybe there is already an answer to my question but I could’t find it then.

I would like to get the page numbers in my `\listoffigures` ragged-right, preferably divided by `|` from the caption.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{
\renewcommand*\l@figure{\@dottedtocline{1}{2.4cm}{.5cm}}
\renewcommand{\@dotsep}{10000}
}
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\bfseries\arabic{figure}}

\begin{document}

    \captionof{figure}{example-image-a}
    \captionof{figure}{example-image-b}
    \captionof{figure}{example-image-c}

\listoffigures
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The macro `\l@figure` actually has 2 arguments which are normally passed on as the last two arguments to  `\@dottedtocline` .

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{
\renewcommand*\l@figure[2]{%
  \ifnum 1>\c@tocdepth \else
    \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
    \vskip \z@ \@plus.2\p@
    {\leftskip 2.4cm\relax
      \parindent 2.4cm\relax\@afterindenttrue
      \interlinepenalty\@M
      \leavevmode
      \@tempdima 0.5cm\relax
      \advance\leftskip \@tempdima \null\nobreak\hskip -\leftskip
      {#1}~{\normalfont \normalcolor #2}%
      \par}%
  \fi}
%\renewcommand*{\l@figure}[2]{\@dottedtocline{1}{2.4cm}{.5cm}{#1}{\hbox to \@pnumwidth{#2\hfill}}}
\renewcommand{\@dotsep}{10000}
}
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\bfseries\arabic{figure}}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures

    \captionof{figure}{example-image-a}
    \newpage\setcounter{page}{10}
    \captionof{figure}{example-image-b}
    \newpage\setcounter{page}{100}
    \captionof{figure}{example-image-c}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I would like to get rid of the space between caption and page number. So page numbers would be written right after the caption.

Comment: Actually, that is even easier.  No \@dottedtocline.

Comment: I don’t get it. would you mind explaining with concrete code?

Comment: It wasn't quite as easy as I had hoped.  I tried using \l@chapter as a guide, but couldn't figure out how to use the 2.4cm and .5cm, so wound up rewriting \@dottedtocline instead.